# Iterating through multidimensional array to output the contents in an inner array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

Despite trying days long I can't get to output the "titles" stored in an array($innerresult) within the array ($SortedResult). I need to be able to access all the elements in $innerresult so that I can display them in the sidemenu on the view(Side menu are nothing but all the titles falling under a category ex: PHP). Any idea/modifications to my code below are most welcome.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('crd_article_desc');
$this->db->where('article_id', $CurrentTitleId);
$query = $this->db->get();      
$result=$query->result_array(); //return fetched data

foreach($result as $value){ 

    $this->db->select('article_title');
    $this->db->from('crd_article_desc');
    $this->db->where('article_category', $value['article_category']);
    $innerquery = $this->db->get();         
    $innerresult=$innerquery->result_array();               
    $SortedResult[$value['article_category']][] =    array($innerresult,$value['article_desc']);   
}
return ($query->num_rows() > 0)?$SortedResult:FALSE;
}
```

Below is how I am trying to access the array in my view

```
if(isset($res)){
    foreach($res as $ArticleCategory=>$title)
{ 
?>            
<h2 class="left"><span class="left_h2"><?php echo $ArticleCategory; ?> </h2>                 
<?php
    foreach($title as $articletitle) {
        $new_friendly_url = friendly_seo_string($articletitle['0']); 
?> 
        <a target="_top" href="<?php echo base_url();?>
<?php 
        echo   $new_friendly_url;   
?>
    ">
<?php 
    echo $articletitle['0']; 
?>
        </a>

<?php 
    } 
} 
}
```

The array

```
Array ( 
    [PHP] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [0] => Array ( 
                    [article_title] => Variables 
                    ) 
                [1] => Array ( 
                    [article_title] => arrays 
                    ) 
                [2] => Array ( 
                    [article_title] => operators 
                    ) 
                [3] => Array ( 
                    [article_title] => loops 
                    ) 
                [4] => Array ( 
                    [article_title] => recursive 
                    ) 
            ) [1] => This is article 1003 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: Do a `print_r($SortedResult)` you may then see how to do it. If not show us the output and someone will help you

Comment: Thanks Riggs. I did print it out now as

Comment: Array ( [PHP] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array (   [article_title] => Variables ) [1] => Array ( [article_title] => arrays ) [2] => Array ( [article_title] => operators ) [3] => Array ( [article_title] => loops ) [4] => Array ( [article_title] => recursive ) ) [1] => This is article 1003 ) ) )

Comment: In future please edit your question, nobody can read code in a comment.

Comment: Apologize. It happened out of hurry..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have created some unnecessary levels in that array, but this should list the Titles

```
foreach ( $SortedResult['PHP'][0][0] as $article )
    echo $article['article_title'];
}
```

And this should list the Category name as well as the title

```
foreach ( $SortedResult as $catName => $inner ){

    foreach( $inner[0][0] as $article){
        echo $catName . ' - ' . $article['article_title'] . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Result:

```
PHP - Variables
PHP - arrays
PHP - operators
PHP - loops
```

Comment: Hi Riggs, Thanks a lot! It outputs the article titles as expected! I do also need to print the key which is a category name all the titles are listed under. In stead of using 'PHP' as the key in your answer I need to put the actual variable that stores the categories such as PHP which means it is dynamically processed. Kindly correct me if I am wrong. This is very interesting thing to explore. Also, Could you please show me a way to minimize the levels in my array yet be able to keep both Category name and the titles in the array. I would be grateful to you.

Comment: Check answer for reply to your comment

Comment: Excellent solution. Several days of my pondering over the issue resolved with your kind help Riggs! Thanks a lot. I am a big fan of multidimensional array. Could you please point me to any best online learning resource on multidimensional array, preferably in PHP.

Comment: Surely will do. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Hi Riggs, I ran to an error while looping through the array as above. Please look into it to find where I went wrong in accessing the elements. Thank you.

Comment: You had better EDIT your question, and no my answer

Comment: Hi Riggs. I have edited my recent question at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42313519/error-message-illegal-offset-while-accessing-the-array-having-a-different-struc?noredirect=1#comment71781192_42313519) Kindly have a look to see what is wrong with it