# Error message: Illegal offset while accessing the array having a different structure than was seen so far

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, foreach

As I kept on resolving the issue I moved further from the last issue that was mentioned here for the people. However, I find it very difficult to get out of the problem accessing the elements in my array as the structure itself seems to be unfamiliar to me. The resultant array is obtained after being assigned with 2 SQL results from the DB as seen below. When looking at the key after printing it out, it seems to appear different from the structures I have seen so far.
If the structure is in the correct form I would like to know how to access article_title,article_desc,article_category from the first row in the array and all the titles from the following rows.I am grateful for your time and the advises. I keep getting the error saying "illegal offset" when trying to access. Please have a look and advise as to what is wrong with it.

```
$sqlarticle1  = "SELECT article_title, article_desc, article_category FROM crd_article_desc where article_id='$CurrentTitleId'";//Get article based on ID.
$sqlarticle2  = "SELECT article_title FROM crd_article_desc where article_category = '$CurrentCategory'";//Fetch all the categories

$result1    = mysqli_query($con,$sqlarticle1);
$result2    = mysqli_query($con,$sqlarticle2);
$finalarray = array();

while($record1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
$finalarray = $record1;
}

while($record2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
$finalarray[] = $record2;
}
```

Structure of the array is

```
Array (
        [0] => Array (  [0] => HTM applications 
                        [article_title] => HTM applications 
                        [1] => Uses of HTML 
                        [article_desc] => Uses of HTML 
                        [2] => HTML 
                        [article_category] => HTML 
                    ) 
        [1] => Array (  [0] => HTML Tags 
                        [article_title] => HTML Tags 
                    ) 
        [2] => Array (  [0] => HTM applications 
                        [article_title] => HTM applications 
                    ) 
        [3] => Array (  [0] => Usage of HTML Elements 
                        [article_title] => Usage of HTML Elements 
                    ) 
        [4] => Array (  [0] => Elements 
                        [article_title] => Elements 
                    ) 
        [5] => Array (  [0] => jobs_codeigniter_page 
                        [article_title] => jobs_codeigniter_page 
                    ) 
    );
```

Below is how I am trying to access the elements from the array.

```
foreach ( $finalarray as $key=>$value ){
    echo $key; 
    foreach($value as $innerkey=>$innervalue) {   
        echo $innervalue['article_title']; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: It is unclear how the two separate statements are connected, you have to describe that in more detail, also mentioning why you cannot do that on SQL level using simple JOINs.

Comment: @arkascha. Thanks. Sorry for the less clarity of my question. I usually use JOINS on 2 separate tables while trying to fetch records from different table via a common field. Here, in this case, the table remains same while the SQL statements are written to fetch different data that needs to be stored in a single variable. Please share any of your thoughts to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have two `foreach` loops to go over the results, your array is not that deep.

```
foreach ( $finalarray as $key=>$value ) {
    echo $key; 
    echo $value["article_title"];
}
```

Also your first `while` loop is pointless, as you're not appending to `$finalarray`. Not sure if that is intentional or not.

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks. But your answer helps print just one title instead 5 articles. I though $finalarray to be an array of array which is accessed usually with 2 or more forloops. Please tell me what I need to change in the loop to get the results wanted. I need to access 'article_title, article_desc, article_category' from this array. I stored 2 SQL query results into one variable. Is this the right way? KIndly check. Thanks  a lot for your help.

Comment: If the array is structured as you say, this code will work.

Comment: I also suggest you address the first comment left 17 hours ago. How are these queries related, and why can't you use a join?

Comment: It would have bee so convenient if I could use a join statement. However, since I am fetching from the same table using 2 queries I don't see how to go about doing that. Please advise how to use join on my queries or any other way to simplify the coding.

Comment: Now I can successfully print all the articles. When I tried to output '$value["article_desc"]' it said Undefined index: article_desc. The index exists in the first row as one of the fields.